# How to use Multi-Select Drop Down Tree Plugin With jQuery - Combo Tree in my asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use Multi-Select Drop Down Tree Plugin With jQuery - Combo Tree in my asp.net application.But getting an error "Custom.aspx:1694 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).comboTree is not a function" error?".I am new to Jquery. I Would really appreciate it if anyone could help.

code in my .aspx page

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
   integrity="sha384- 
   nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="comboTreePlugin.js"></script>
  <script src="icontains.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

        var myData = [

            {                   
                id: 0,
                title:'Item 1 '
                }, 
                {
                id: 1,
                title:'Item 2',
                subs: [
                {
                    id: 10,
                    title:'Item 2-1'
                }, {
                    id: 11,
                    title:'Item 2-2'
                }, {
                    id: 12,
                    title:'Item 2-3'
                }]                  
                }, 
                ];
                                    
                $('#example').comboTree({
                            source : myData

            }); 


</script>

<td width="270px" valign="top" align="center"> 
                        <asp:TextBox ID="example" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling JQuery function, you need to make sure JQuery has loaded, which can be done using `$(document).ready(function() { });`.

You will also need to make sure the combo tree plugin has loaded. However I can't see the plugin in your question. Also you might need to add static ID (unless it's setup in your web.config). To add it to textbox try e.g:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="example" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Anyway try  adding the following:

```
var myData = [/* add array */ ]
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').comboTree({ source : myData }); 
});
```

For a full working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="comboTreePlugin.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myData = [
            {
                id: 0,
                title: 'Item 1 '
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                title: 'Item 2',
                subs: [
                    {
                        id: 10,
                        title: 'Item 2-1'
                    }, {
                        id: 11,
                        title: 'Item 2-2'
                    }, {
                        id: 12,
                        title: 'Item 2-3'
                    }]
            },
        ];

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').comboTree({
                source: myData
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">        
        <asp:TextBox ID="example" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Greg, I made the changes you suggested and updated my questions and also added plugin code in a question, but, still getting an error 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).comboTree is not a function".

Comment: Can you supply the comoTree plugin? Hopefully they have a CDN?

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
   integrity="sha384- 
   nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="comboTreePlugin.js"></script>
  <script src="icontains.js"></script>

Comment: That's what I am using to import the comboTree. Does not look like it is liking it.

Comment: Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/3ojh5vLc/1/. I've copied the plugin from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erhanfirat/combo-tree/master/comboTreePlugin.js and changed the ASP:TextBox to html input

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using JQuery 1.12 and not the latest (3.4.1)? That might cause issues with the plugin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218363/discussion-between-osheca-and-greg).